# How to schedule jobs in Sql server 2008 for less than 10 sec?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs

I want to run a job every 3 seconds, however in SQL Server 2008 we cannot define an interval of less than 10 seconds.

The job is used to insert/update visitor information, and segmentation information into a database which is tracked by google search.

There are up to about 100 rows inserted in a 2 or 3 seconds. That job inserts and update the table in a database. Is there any way to schedule it using sp job scheduling configuration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a job that is scheduled to start every minute.  Have the job do something like:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure; /*  this would be the 
        name of a stored procedure that does the 
        actual work */
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.000';
END
```

Comment: Wont this just spawn the same infinitely-looping job every minute until the end of time?

Comment: No, any given job can only ever have a single instance running at any given time.

Comment: If the job fails or is stopped, it will restart in approximately 1 minute.

Comment: Ah okay. I was wondering if that was the case but I didn't have a chance to try it. Carry on, nothing to see here.

Comment: worth noting that you need to tell the loop to quit if you want the jobstep to write success or failure to the log.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think this answer is correct. The reason is as follows:
let's say dbo.SomeProcedure will run for 2 seconds and it starts at 10:00:00am, then after this proc finishes, it will wait for another 3 seconds before restart again, i.e. at 10:00:02am, it finishes, and it will not start until 10:00:05am.
While if we could really schedule a job to run every 3 seconds, dbo.SomeProcedure will indeed run at 10:00:00am and 10:00:03am, and so on so forth. The more accurate one should be the following:

```
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
      EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure; /*  this would be the 
      name of a stored procedure that does the actual work */

      WHILE datediff(second, @dt, getdate())%3 <> 0
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100'; -- can be made it to '00:00:00.001'
   END
```